# Merge [date] and [time] into [datetime]?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Currently on SO there is a group of similar tags:

- [date](/questions/tagged/date) (8059)
- [time](/questions/tagged/time) (4238)
- [datetime](/questions/tagged/datetime) (8204)

I think D and T should be merged into DT, or at least D.

Comment: Why would you do that? Not even in spoken language those can be merged.."What time is it today?" "What's the date?" Are completely different (and are wrong too) from "what date is today?" and "WHat's the time?". Imagine in a programming language then...As for data types, I only know MySQL and that has enough reasons alone to reject your proposal

Comment: @DamienPirsy: Because there are a lot of questions tagged by both [date] and [datetime] and that makes no sense to me.

Comment: Well, the problem is yours then. DATE is a...date, while DATETIME is..a date plus the time. I don't see how they could be equal. Another example: in php, date() does something, time() something else, and datetime() doesn't exist as a built-in function. Just saying. COuld you be more specific on why those tags don't make sense to you? not just a feeling, but an argumentative answer

Comment: PS: I see now your quest on correcting tags and by skimming the upvotes it looks like a good job. But  there's a saying whereI live (don't know the english equivalent):"Not all the donuts come out with a hole"; I think you've been overzealous this time ;)

Comment: @DamienPirsy: Seems that I've been indeed. btw here's [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time+datetime) [links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date+datetime)

Comment: Uhm, people's mistagging isn't a reason _per se_ to say that tags are wrong. Should I propose to merge jQuery and javascript too, since people are always using them in conjunction, and jQUery is javascript?

Comment: @DamienPirsy: Agree with the first part, and don't with the second. I think both should be used when a free space available. The same for .net and c#, sql and tsql, etc.

Answer (score 7):

No, I wouldn't.

Some languages explicitely differ between `date` and `datetime` data types and questions about these types can be very specific. Imo, having distinct tags for them is a good thing.